# Generating random circuits with only CNOT gates using qiskit.circuit.random.random_circuit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, random-quantum-circuit

I am trying to generate a random quantum circuit with 5 qubits using only CNOT gates. I have modified the source code of the qiskit.circuit.random.random_circuit function to only include CNOT gates (Making `num_operands = 2` and `two_q_ops = [CXGate]`) but I am getting an error. My code is as follows -

```
def random_circuit(num_qubits, depth, max_operands=3, measure=False, conditional=False, reset=False, seed=None):

    if max_operands < 1 or max_operands > 3:
        raise CircuitError("max_operands must be between 1 and 3")

    one_q_ops = [IGate, U1Gate, U2Gate, U3Gate, XGate, YGate, ZGate, HGate, SGate, SdgGate, TGate, TdgGate, RXGate, RYGate, RZGate]
    one_param = [U1Gate, RXGate, RYGate, RZGate, RZZGate, CU1Gate, CRZGate]
    two_param = [U2Gate]
    three_param = [U3Gate, CU3Gate]
    two_q_ops = [CXGate]
    three_q_ops = [CCXGate, CSwapGate]

    qr = QuantumRegister(num_qubits, "q")
    qc = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)

    if measure or conditional:
        cr = ClassicalRegister(num_qubits, "c")
        qc.add_register(cr)

    if reset:
        one_q_ops += [Reset]

    if seed is None:
        seed = np.random.randint(0, np.iinfo(np.int32).max)
    rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)

    # apply arbitrary random operations at every depth
    for _ in range(depth):
        # choose either 1, 2, or 3 qubits for the operation
        remaining_qubits = list(range(num_qubits))
        rng.shuffle(remaining_qubits)
        while remaining_qubits:
            max_possible_operands = min(len(remaining_qubits), max_operands)
            num_operands = 2
            operands = [remaining_qubits.pop() for _ in range(num_operands)]
            if num_operands == 1:
                operation = rng.choice(one_q_ops)
            elif num_operands == 2:
                operation = rng.choice(two_q_ops)
            elif num_operands == 3:
                operation = rng.choice(three_q_ops)
            if operation in one_param:
                num_angles = 1
            elif operation in two_param:
                num_angles = 2
            elif operation in three_param:
                num_angles = 3
            else:
                num_angles = 0
            angles = [rng.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi) for x in range(num_angles)]
            register_operands = [qr[i] for i in operands]
            op = operation(*angles)

            # with some low probability, condition on classical bit values
            if conditional and rng.choice(range(10)) == 0:
                value = rng.integers(0, np.power(2, num_qubits))
                op.condition = (cr, value)

            qc.append(op, register_operands)

    if measure:
        qc.measure(qr, cr)

    return qc

qc = random_circuit(num_qubits = 5, depth = 10)
```

The error that is thrown up is -

```
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1268/4128137234.py in <module>
----> 1 qc = random_circuit(num_qubits = 5, depth = 10)
      2 qc.draw(output='mpl')

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1268/430653575.py in random_circuit(num_qubits, depth, max_operands, measure, conditional, reset, seed)
     49             max_possible_operands = min(len(remaining_qubits), max_operands)
     50             num_operands = 2
---> 51             operands = [remaining_qubits.pop() for _ in range(num_operands)]
     52             if num_operands == 1:
     53                 operation = rng.choice(one_q_ops)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1268/430653575.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     49             max_possible_operands = min(len(remaining_qubits), max_operands)
     50             num_operands = 2
---> 51             operands = [remaining_qubits.pop() for _ in range(num_operands)]
     52             if num_operands == 1:
     53                 operation = rng.choice(one_q_ops)

IndexError: pop from empty list
```

This error does not occur when I try the same code for 4 qubits. What can I change so that it works for 5 qubits as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add:

```
if max_possible_operands < 2:
    break
```

before:

```
num_operands = 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much!